# jQuery: Is req.readyState == 3 possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a big fan of jQuery and I use it for 95% of all my Javascript needs. However, I am a loading a live page using a COMET method; where in Javascript I retreive the data using AJAX at the point where `req.readyState == 3`. I was curious if it's possible to do this with jQuery `$.ajax` too (I couldn't find anything in the documentation).

Answer (score 3):

As specified at https://coderwall.com/p/gi-f2g/accessing-the-xhr-object-in-jquery-s-ajax

```
var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

//Do what you want with the XHR Object. For Example:

xhr.upload.addEventListener( function( event ) {
//CODE!!!
}, false );

//Store the XHR in a closure.
function xhrProvider() { 
    return xhr;
}

//Then when using $.ajax specifiy a custom xhr like this:
$.ajax( {
    url: 'http://w00wz3rs.com',
    xhr: xhrProvider
} );
```

Comment: The object returned by `$.ajax` does not contain a `onreadystatechange` property.